# Variables C String string.h useage

Tags: c, string, variables, c-strings

Hi i just started with c and the string.h (strings.h?) and i don't find much tutorials about it, so some questions for me are remaining like:

So until now i was using

```
char name[10];
```

for example, is there a way to use like

```
string name
```

to have a variable as a string?

At last i want todo something like

```
int main (){
    string name;

    puts("name?");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("%s",filname);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like string in C

The best you can do declare the string is like this:

```
char greeting[] = "Hello";
```

or like this:

```
char greeting[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm).

> The string in C programming language is actually a one-dimensional
>   array of characters which is terminated by a null character '\0'. Thus
>   a null-terminated string contains the characters that comprise the
>   string followed by a null.

Answer (score 1):

There is no string in C. Essentially, in C string is nothing but an array of chars.
You can use `char*` which is a pointer to a char variable. I don't know how much do you know about C pointers but when you do something like
`int a[10]`
which is an array declaration a pointer to integers is saved in as variable `a`. So it's the same in chars if you use `char*` as a pointer to a char you have a char array with no default size. But be careful when working with pointers you can face so many run time errors so be careful when writing codes involving pointers.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no dynamically-allocated string type built into C.  There are hundreds of libraries that provide such string classes, if you need one, but as for the standard library functions like scanf, you'll need to figure out the maximum size ahead of time (or resort to lower-level functions).

Answer (score 0):

There is no datatype called a string in c.A character array is a string and you use it as follows.

```
char s[10];
scanf("%s",s);
printf(s);
```

You will find these functions useful, which come under string.h

`strlen(s)` gives string length

`strcat(s1,s2)` joins or concatenates s2 to s1

`strcpy(s1,s2)` copies s2 to s1

Answer (score 0):

take a look about string reference (c++) :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: The question was about C, _not_ C++.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have classes and std::string is a class in c++, you have access to all the c-string functions though [The C String Library](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/cstring/)

Answer (score 0):

Cant he do it with the

```
 #include <string.h>
```

Comment: I suggest searching for `string.h` on your computer and reading the contents. i did and i don't believe so..